# What is alternative to `registerGeneratedResFolders` with AGP 7.0.0+?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to update the AGP version to `7.0.0-beta03` from `4.1.2` and I ran into an issue with our tasks that generate resources.

Currently with android gradle plugin `4.1.2,` we have code like this registering generated resources from a task:

```kotlin
afterEvaluate {
    android.libraryVariants.all {
        val outputPath = "$buildDir/generated/res/foo/$flavorName/${buildType.name}"

        val resourceGeneratingTask = tasks.register(...)

        val outputDirectory = project.file(outputPath)
        val outputs = project.files(outputDirectory).builtBy(resourceGeneratingTask)
        registerGeneratedResFolders(outputs)
    }
}
```

After bumping to `7.0.0-beta03`, where `android.libraryVariants` seems to be removed and replaced with `androidComponents.onVariants {}`, I am failing to find a way to hook our generated resources into the build. I see `addResValue` in the api, but that seems to be valid only for resources in `values` our generated resources are `raw` or `drawable`.

I found [a medium article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/new-apis-in-the-android-gradle-plugin-f5325742e614) introducing the variant APIs and also a [github repository](https://github.com/android/gradle-recipes/tree/agp-7.0) with gradle recipes for android, but did not find anything helping our case.